# how to write procedure to insert data in to the table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have created table as below:

```
student:
+----+------+-----------+--------+
|uid | name | user_name | branch |
+----+------+-----------+--------+
|    |      |           |        |
+----+------+-----------+--------+
```

I want to insert data in to the table using procedure.

the procedure which i wrote is:

> create procedure add(in_name varchar(50),in_user_name
>   varchar(50),in_branch varchar(50))
>   begin
>   insert into student
>   (name,user_name,branch) values (in_name ,in_user_name,in_branch);
>   end;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (IN name varchar(50),IN user_name varchar(50),IN branch varchar(50))
BEGIN
    insert into student (name,user_name,branch) values (name ,user_name,branch);
END
```

Comment: thanks.,its working well.
at the time of call i just need to pass the values?
exmp:
`call simpleproc ('hatjeet','jadeja','i.s.e')`

Comment: but when i am trying that is gives me below error:
`#1054 - Unknown column 'in_name' in 'field list'`

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Can a MySQL prepared statement be use inside of this stored procedure to insert the row, or would that make everything break? I am playing around trying to do this, but it does not work. No errors. No records inserted. Just wondering. Thanks.

Comment: Is a procedure like this protection against basic SQL injection attempts?

Answer (score 6):

```
# Switch delimiter to //, so phpMyAdmin will not execute it line by line.
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_rateChapter12

(IN numRating_Chapter INT(11) UNSIGNED, 

 IN txtRating_Chapter VARCHAR(250),

 IN chapterName VARCHAR(250),

 IN addedBy VARCHAR(250)

)

BEGIN
DECLARE numRating_Chapter INT;

DECLARE txtRating_Chapter VARCHAR(250);

DECLARE chapterName1 VARCHAR(250);

DECLARE addedBy1 VARCHAR(250);

DECLARE chapterId INT;

DECLARE studentId INT;

SET chapterName1 = chapterName;
SET addedBy1 = addedBy;

SET chapterId = (SELECT chapterId 
                   FROM chapters 
                   WHERE chaptername = chapterName1);

SET studentId = (SELECT Id 
                   FROM students 
                   WHERE email = addedBy1);

SELECT chapterId;
SELECT studentId;

INSERT INTO ratechapter (rateBy, rateText, rateLevel, chapterRated)
VALUES (studentId, txtRating_Chapter, numRating_Chapter,chapterId);

END //

//DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 3):

This method work for me:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db.test $$
CREATE PROCEDURE db.test(IN id INT(12),IN NAME VARCHAR(255))
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO USER VALUES(id,NAME);
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```