# Retrieve dynamic input and enter on the bench with procedure

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to enter the data received from a dynamic input the procedure only enter once, I follow my code where I get the data it seems that the loop does not work:

```
$ddd     = $_POST['ddd'];
   $userid  = $_POST['userid'];
   $idusuario = $_POST['idusuario'];
   $telefone    = $_POST['telefone'];
   $obs         = $_POST['obs'];
   $quant_linhas = count($ddd);

   for ($i=0; $i<$quant_linhas; $i++) {

        $sql = "Call telefone_i(
        '".$userid[$i]."',
        '".$ddd[$i]."',
        '".$telefone[$i]."',
        '".$obs[$i]."',
        '".$idusuario[$i]."'
         )";    
   }
```

My inputs are created dynamic with jquery:

```
<div class="content" style="min-height: 150px;">
   <!-- CONTEUDO INICIO -->
    <center>
        <h2  style="background-color: #DDEBFF">Cadastrar Telefone</h2>
    </center>
    <div style=" margin-left:5px; padding: 5px; width: 600px; overflow:auto; border:#036 thin; border-style:dotted;">

<form action="telefone_inserir.php?id=<?php echo $usuario_id; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="list">
    <thead>
        <tr class="linhas">

            <td width="25%" class="right">DDD</td>

            <td class="left">

            <input type="text" name="ddd[]" value="" maxlength="2" style="width: 30px" />

            <input name="userid[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

            <input name="idusuario[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $usuario_id; ?>" />

            </td>

            <td width="25%" class="right">Telefone</td>

            <td class="left"><input type="text" name="telefone[]" value="" maxlength="9" style="width: 80px" /></td>

            <td width="25%" class="right">OBS:</td>

            <td class="left"><input type="text" name="obs[]" value="" maxlength="45" style="width: 200px" /></td>
            <td class="left"><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="imagens/exc_btn.png" border="0" /></a></td>

        </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="7">
        <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="imagens/tel_btn.png" border="0" /></a>
    </td></tr>

         <tr>

            <td colspan="7" align="center" height="50">
                <input name="botao" type="image" value="Alterar" id="btn_salvar" src="imagens/cadastrar_btn.png">

            </td>
          </tr>


          </thead>
        </table>

    </form>

    </div>
<!-- CONTEUDO FIM -->
</div>
```

my procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `telefone_i`(
p_usuario_id int(11) ,
p_ddd int(3) ,
p_telefone int(9) ,
p_obs varchar(45) ,
p_usuario_lancamento int(11)
)
BEGIN

insert acad.telefone
    set
        usuario_id = p_usuario_id,
        ddd = p_ddd,
        telefone = p_telefone,
        obs = p_obs,
        data_lancamento = current_timestamp,
        usuario_lancamento = p_usuario_lancamento;
END
```

Comment: Hey opeta -  this question doesn't actually explain what isn't working. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @RobbieAverill 
the loop does not work and only makes an insert

Comment: Hi opeta - you still aren't explaining what the code is supposed to do. All you're doing is overwriting the `$sql` variable in a loop. What do you do with it afterwards? If whatever you're doing that isn't shown here is only happening once, it'll be because you're overwriting `$sql` in the loop instead of appending to it - change `$sql =` to `$sql .=`

Comment: @RobbieAverill It is a form with input dynamic created with jquery where the user fills out how many phones you want after sending I created a loop to record only that only records the first line

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Thanks for sharing the procedure. Change `$sql =` to `$sql .=` and ensure you add a `;` at the end of the procedure call

Comment: Basic stuff from here on out - initialize your variables, enable error reporting and implement good error handling. Good luck.

Comment: checkout this tutorial : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018488/how-to-write-procedure-to-insert-data-in-to-the-table-in-phpmyadmin