# MySQL create a product reference code based on the product details

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched if the same question exists but i can't find any answer to this or tutorial.

If have have a database table in MySQL (`product_table`) with 8 columns starting with `product_id` , `product_name`, `time_created` , `reference_code` , `product_color` , `product_type`, `product_price` , `product_description`.

I just want to know if it is possible to generate `reference_code` based on the fields around it, like `product_name`, `time_created`.

So let's say:

`product_name = Hat`

`time_created = 2017-09-18 17:08:21`

`product_color = red`

I would like the **reference_code**(`reference_code`) to look like this just as example could be any of the following, it should just be based on the product's own details.

`reference_code = Hat2017-09-18red`

`reference_code = Hat20170918red`

`reference_code = Hat17:08:21red`

Any help or link to a description would be much appreciated.

Comment: yep just concatenate the fields using + when you run a select query on the table. You can do it in SQL, or somewhere in the PHP object layer if it makes things more flexible. No need to store the value in the DB since it's a derivable value. BTW from a design/UX point of view, if you're showing this to users as if it were a unique reference number (it's not!), make sure that duplicates are not possible (e.g. same product, date and colour) and that those fields cannot be later amended (so that the reference changes, which would be confusing).

Comment: In mysql 5.7.6 + you can also create [virtual generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html) with the specified column values. eg: `ALTER TABLE product_table
 ADD COLUMN reference_code VARCHAR(255) AS (CONCAT(product_name, DATE(time_created), product_color)) VIRTUAL AFTER product_color;`.  Will output `Hat2017-09-18red`.

Comment: Thanks both you guys  ,make sense and i agree , ill also check this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.

The issue is if you want to do it as a proccess in your db or as a result in the PHP.

If you are submiting a form while you proccess the data you can create a variable and assign it to the field in question:

```
$newvariable = $_POST['a'].$_POST['b'].$_POST['c'];
```

As a procedure, I recomend you to see this post:

[how to write procedure to insert data in to the table in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018488/how-to-write-procedure-to-insert-data-in-to-the-table-in-phpmyadmin)